# Script Concat / Minify Task Keeps Running

Tags: gulp

So I have a task like so:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app/scripts/app.js', 'app/scripts/controllers/**/*.js', 'app/scripts/services/**/*.js', 'app/scripts/directives/**/*.js', 'app/scripts/libs/**/*.js' ])
        .pipe(concat('external.min.js'))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
});
```

and I have a watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['sass-dev', 'scripts'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/style/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass-dev']);
    gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

All works well, except whenever I save a JS file, "scripts" runs multiple times. I'm assuming the problem lies with the gulp.src and it looking at multiple files, but I'm not sure.

This is no big deal (to me), but sometimes I'll swap over to the command line and the task is running infinitely. It just keeps getting called over and over again.

If you haven't already guessed, I'm running Angular, which is why app.js is first and I have ngAnnotate.

Can someone shed some light on why the script runs continuously sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is `.pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'))`. You're doing some stuff (uglify and angular stuff) with your scripts and then you place them in the same folder you're watching. So the `scripts` task will launch again and again and again.

You should remove this line and only place your distribution scripts in your distribution folder and leave your app files untouched.

Comment: Completely overlooked that. It's so simple too! haha. Thanks. That solved my issue.